# If $F$ is a compact subset of a metric space $X$, prove $F$ is closed

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I was asked to prove this in an exam.

I began by proving that $X \setminus F$ is open. I assumed there was an $x\in X\setminus F$ such that $x_k\rightarrow x$. Then draw a ball of radius $r=d(x,y_i)/2$ where $y_i$ is a point in $F$. Then since $X$ is compact we only need a fixed number of $y_i$'s. Hence denote $r=\min r_i$. As $x_k \rightarrow x$ there is a $k$ such that $d(x,x_k)<r$. Conclude that there is a violation of the trangle inequality, thus $X \setminus F$ is indeed open, since $x_k$ can't be in both balls.

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean if $F$ is a compact subset of $X$?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is definitely not true that every subset $F$ of a compact space $X$ is closed. What condition(s) do you have on $F$? And also on $X$ - is it a compact **metric space**? You didn't say so but you use distance and balls.

Comment: Suppose X is a closed interval on the real line.  X is compact.  Suppose F is an open interval that is in X.  F is an open subset of X.

Comment: @mathguy Yes, metric spaces, sorry my head is not functioning properly anymore

Comment: @Nitin yes, that's what I meant sorry

Comment: I just want to know if I went in the right direction, or not?